# Not able to embed icon on shortcut?

Tags: nsis

I created an window application for which I need to create setup.For creating setup i am using NSIS.
I had written script to create setup file which creates shortcut on **Desktop  and Star Menu** now i need to embed an icon to the shortcut.Code is as follows:

```
 Function "CREATE"
   createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\lnkname.lnk" "$DESKTOP\Application.exe" "ADC" "$DESKTOP\icon.ico" 0
   createShortCut "$DESKTOP\lnkname.lnk" "$DESKTOP\ApplicationMDMO\ApplicationMDMO\bin\debug\Application.exe" "ADC" "$DESKTOP\icon.ico" 0
 FunctionEnd
```

Now I created an uninstaller to this installer.In this uninstaller I am deleting the shortcut file and the application file which are installed by installer.

```
 Function "Uninstall"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\*.*"
     Delete "$DESKTOP\lnkname.lnk"
    Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\lnkname.lnk"
 FunctionEnd
```

Problem:

- When I am trying to delete the shortcuts which are at **desktop and all programs** the all program short cut doesn't get deleted unless I add this code.

  ```
   RequestExecutionLevel admin //at the beginning

    SetShellVarContext all // at the section
  ```

  But when I add these to lines the icon disappears
- When I am excluding the code written in the above code the shortcut at "all Programs " is not purged.

Comment: You did not even show us how you create the Shortcut. Can you please post a complete minimal version of your script that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Anders Thanks for this comment.I shared some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `SetShellVarContext all` the path `$DESKTOP` resolves to might change if you had to elevate with UAC etc.

I assume you are not really installing the application .exe and other files on the users desktop? If you place the .exe and the .ico somewhere under `$ProgramFiles` it should work...

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"

Section
SetShellVarContext all
SetOutPath "$InstDir"
File myapp.exe
File myapp.ico
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\myapp.lnk" "$InstDir\myapp.exe" "" "$InstDir\myapp.ico" 0
SectionEnd
```